# Converting a string of digits to double in C++

Tags: c++, string, floating-point, double

Here I am trying to convert a string of digits into its corresponding double number.

```
double string_to_double ( const char* str)
{

int i = 0;
double* num = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
*num = 0;
int fract_fact = 10;
int size = strlen(str);

if ( str[0] != '.')  // if its not starting with a point then take out the first decimal digit and place it in the number instead of 0.

  *num = (str[i] - '0');


for ( i = 1; i < size; ++i){

    if ( str[i] == '.'){

        i++;

        for (int j = i; j < size; ++j){ // after encountering point the rest of the part is fractional.


            *num += (str[j] - '0') / fract_fact; // summing up the next fractional digit.
            fract_fact *= 10; // increasing the farct_fact by a factor of 10 so that next fractional digit can be added rightly.
        }

        break;
    }

    *num = *num * 10 + ( str[i] - '0');
}

return *num;
}
```

When I call it as follows from main

```
cout << string_to_double("123.22");
```

Its output is

> 123

But why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Downvoter please mention some reason?

Comment: I assume using something like `atof` is out of the question?

Comment: That's a very evil way to leak memory...

Comment: @belph Don't use `atof` there is no error checking

Comment: i am just trying it my way

Comment: Why do you allocate num on the heap instead of using it directly?

Comment: @zenith oh please tell me what i have asked

Comment: @NathanOliver Well of course, but, seeing as there's no error checking in the question, I was just assuming that `str` being a valid `char*` representation of a `double` was some sort of logical invariant which was otherwise being enforced.

Comment: First of all, you have a memory leak. Every time you call the function you dynamically allocate memory, which is not needed. Returning by value copies the value. Secondly, use a *debugger* and step through the code, line by line, to find what the problem might be.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 5):

```
*num += (str[j] - '0') / fract_fact;
```

should be

```
*num += (str[j] - '0') / (double)fract_fact;
```

Your version does integer arithmetic, which always evaluates to zero.

Not the question you asked but why are you allocating num?

```
double num;

num = ...

return num;
```

Much simpler, and it doesn't leak memory.

Comment: Just a note to the OP: There's no need to allocate any primitive datatypes. It's almost always only a good idea to call `malloc` when working with either structures or arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with standard functions very easily.

```
std::size_t end = 0;
std::string string_number = "123.456";
double number = stod(string_number, &end);
if (end == string_number.size())
    std::cout << "the number is " << number;
else
    std::cout << "error in conversion";
```

Comment: don't need to initialize end??

Comment: @Rouftantical AFAIK no as it get set to position of the last converted character.  I updated it anyways to be proper